# How can I change the background colour of a single emacs buffer?

Tags: emacs, colors, themes

I want to make SQL interactive buffers that are connected to production DBs very, very obvious, so my thought was to change the background of the buffer to a dark red colour.

`set-background-color` doesn't work, though; it sets the colour of all frames to the specified colour.

How can I change the background of just a single buffer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've created a emacs lisp package for this: https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local it  uses Emacs' Face remapping to install theme faces locally.

```
(require 'color-theme-buffer-local)
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda nil (color-theme-buffer-local 'color-theme-robin-hood (current-buffer)) ))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

The background color is generally frame-specific.

You can set the background color of the `default` face to be frame specific using [`set-face-background`](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/elisp-manual-20-2.5/html_node/elisp_631.html), like so:

```
(set-face-background 'default "#CCCCCC" (window-frame (frame-selected-window))
```

Frame customizations are generally controlled through [frame parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Frame-Parameters.html).  Now, if you look closely at the [`background-color` for frame parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Font-and-Color-Parameters.html#Font-and-Color-Parameters), you'll see that the default background color is taken from the `default` face - which is why the above elisp has an effect.

Past that, it seems the closes you can come to a buffer background color is by using the minor-mode [`buffer-face-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.1) (added in 23.1) - however that only changes the background for the **text** of a buffer, and not the entire background.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it, but http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferBackgroundColor sounds like a 
possible solution.

Comment: Nice idea, but it uses overlays, so it only changes the background of text.