# How can I customize the background color of the selected window in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors

Related: [How can I change the background colour of a single emacs buffer?](https://superuser.com/q/153784/)

I would like to change the background color of the active buffer to, say, `white`. This sort of thing is possible as demonstrated by the linked question, but I am unsure how to go about hooking onto a change in the active buffer.  How can this be done in a way that is robust whether I change with `*-other-window` or by clicking / mousing over?

Comment: See also this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20936397/2112489  I've since updated / modified the code in my personal setup, but what is there is pretty close to what I currently use.  I currently also change the color of the active mode-line depending upon the major or minor mode.

Comment: @lawlist I discovered the active modeline group a little over a week ago---it's very helpful, but perhaps I'm just extremely unobservant `:)`

Comment: I don't think what I do is 100% robust but it works most of the time. I use defadvice on other-window, select-window, and select-frame, and I also use window-configuration-change-hook. [Here's the code I use](http://amitp.blogspot.com/2013/05/emacs-highlight-active-buffer.html)

Comment: @amitp is not robust, but I guess a good start.